# This is the section my scripts I've been working on this problem for the last for hours. Stakeholder contract isn't recognized

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

Error i got

$ npx hardhat run scripts/1_deploy-app.js --network hardhat
Error: No Contract deployed with name: Stakeholder
at getContract (C:\Users\SAMSON\Desktop\LORD\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\helpers.ts:149:11)
at main (C:\Users\SAMSON\Desktop\LORD\scripts\1_deploy-app.js:5:25)

This is the section of my unit testing... I've been working on this problem for the last few hours. I couldn't, however... Stakaholder contract isn't recognized... (Note- All the deployments are working correctly... )

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function main () {
    const Stakeholder = await ethers.getContract("Stakeholder");
    const Farmer = await ethers.getContract("Farmer");
    const Manufacturer = await ethers.getContract("Manufacturer");
    const Product = await ethers.getContract("Product");
    const Main = await ethers.getContract("Main");

    

    const stakeholderContract = await Stakeholder.deploy();
    const farmerContract = await Farmer.deploy();
    const manufacturerContract = await Manufacturer.deploy();
    const productContract  = await Product.deploy();
    const mainContract = await Main.deploy(farmerContract.address, manufacturerContract.address, stakeholderContract.address);
    
    const accounts = await web3.ethers.getAccounts();

    const admin = accounts[0];
    const farmer1 = accounts[1];
    const farmer2 = accounts[2];
    const manufacturer1 = accounts[3];
    const manufacturer2 = accounts[4];
    const distributer = accounts[5];
    const retailer1 = accounts[6];
    const retailer2 = accounts[7];
    const consumer1 = accounts[8];
    const consumer2 = accounts[9];


    await stakeholderContract.register("Admin", "Internet", "admin", { from: admin });
    await farmerContract.registerFarmer("Farmer 1", "West India", "farmer", ["Milk", "Cocoa", "Sugar", "Apple", "Banana"], { from: farmer1 });
    await farmerContract.registerFarmer("Farmer 2", "North India", "farmer", ["Rice", "Cocoa", "Wheat", "Tomato", "Sugar"], { from: farmer2 });
    await manufacturerContract.register("Cadbury", "Uxbridge, United Kingdom", "manufacturer", { from: manufacturer1 });
    await manufacturerContract.register("Nestle", "Vevey, Switzerland", "manufacturer", { from: manufacturer2 });
    await stakeholderContract.register("Distributer", "New Delhi, India", "distributer", { from: distributer });
    await stakeholderContract.register("Big Mart", "Greater Noida, India", "retailer", { from: retailer1 });
    await stakeholderContract.register("Annapurna", "Greater Noida, India", "retailer", { from: retailer2 });
    await stakeholderContract.register("Mohan", "Greater Noida, India", "consumer", { from: consumer1 });
    await stakeholderContract.register("Sohan", "Greater Noida, India", "consumer", { from: consumer2 });

    console.log(await farmerContract.getFarmer(farmer1, { from: farmer1 }));
    console.log(await farmerContract.getFarmer(farmer2, { from: farmer2 }));
    console.log(await manufacturerContract.get(manufacturer1, { from: manufacturer1 }));
    console.log(await manufacturerContract.get(manufacturer2, { from: manufacturer2 }));
    console.log(await stakeholderContract.get(distributer, { from: distributer }));
    console.log(await stakeholderContract.get(retailer1, { from: retailer1 }));
    console.log(await stakeholderContract.get(retailer2, { from: retailer2 }));
    console.log(await stakeholderContract.get(consumer1, { from: consumer1 }));
    console.log(await stakeholderContract.get(consumer2, { from: consumer2 }));
    console.log(await farmerContract.getRawProductFarmers("Cocoa", { from: farmer1 }));

    await farmerContract.verify(farmer2, { from: admin });
  console.log(await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 }));

  //1st manufacturer
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Cocoa", [
    {
      id: farmer1,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer1, { from: farmer1 })
    },
    {
      id: farmer2,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 })
    }
  ], { from: manufacturer1 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Milk", [
    {
      id: farmer1,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer1, { from: farmer1 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer1 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Wheat", [
    {
      id: farmer2,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer1 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Sugar", [
    {
      id: farmer1,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer1, { from: farmer1 })
    },
    {
      id: farmer2,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 })
    }
  ], { from: manufacturer1 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Banana", [
    {
      id: farmer1,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer1, { from: farmer1 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer1 });

  //2nd Manufacturer
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Cocoa", [
    {
      id: farmer2,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer2 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Apple", [
    {
      id: farmer1,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer1, { from: farmer1 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer2 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Rice", [
    {
      id: farmer2,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer2 });
  await manufacturerContract.addRawProduct("Tomato", [
    {
      id: farmer2,
      isVerified: await farmerContract.isVerified(farmer2, { from: farmer2 })
    },
  ], { from: manufacturer2 });




  const manufacturer1RawProducts = await manufacturerContract.getManufacturerRawProductDetails(manufacturer1, { from: manufacturer1 });
  manufacturer1RawProductsMap = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < manufacturer1RawProducts.length; i++) {
    manufacturer1RawProductsMap[manufacturer1RawProducts[i].name] = manufacturer1RawProducts[i].isVerified;
  }
  console.log(manufacturer1RawProductsMap);

  console.log(await manufacturerContract.getManufacturer(manufacturer1, {from : admin}));

  await productContract.add(
    12091, 
    "Dairy Milk", 
    [
      {
        name: "Milk",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Milk"]
      },
      {
        name: "Sugar",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Sugar"]
      },
      {
        name: "Wheat",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Wheat"]
      }
    ],
    
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/A_white_irish_goat.jpg/180px-A_white_irish_goat.jpg",
    {from: manufacturer1}
  );
    {from: manufacturer1}
  

  await manufacturerContract.launchProduct(12091, {from: manufacturer1});

  await productContract.add(
    12092, 
    "5 Star Chocolate", 
    [
      {
        name: "Milk",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Milk"]
      },
      {
        name: "Sugar",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Sugar"]
      },
      {
        name: "Wheat",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Wheat"]
      }
    ],
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/dstmsi8qv/image/upload/v1652423804/Supply%20Chain/Product%20images/5star_cadbury_emfynn.webp",
    {from: manufacturer1}
  );
  await manufacturerContract.launchProduct(12092, {from: manufacturer1});

  await productContract.add(
    12093, 
    "Banana Cake", 
    [
      {
        name: "Milk",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Milk"]
      },
      {
        name: "Sugar",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Sugar"]
      },
      {
        name: "Wheat",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Wheat"]
      },
      {
        name: "Banana",
        isVerified: manufacturer1RawProductsMap["Banana"]
      }
    ],
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/dstmsi8qv/image/upload/v1652423804/Supply%20Chain/Product%20images/cake_cadbury_tw16tw.jpg",
    {from: manufacturer1}
  );
  await manufacturerContract.launchProduct(12093, {from: manufacturer1});

  //Manufacturer2 Launch Product

  let manufacturer2RawProducts = await manufacturerContract.getManufacturerRawProductDetails(manufacturer2, { from: manufacturer2 });
  manufacturer2RawProductsMap = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < manufacturer2RawProducts.length; i++) {
    manufacturer2RawProductsMap[manufacturer2RawProducts[i].name] = manufacturer2RawProducts[i].isVerified;
  }
  console.log(manufacturer2RawProductsMap);

  console.log(await manufacturerContract.getManufacturer(manufacturer2, {from : admin}));

  await productContract.add(
    22091, 
    "Munch Chocolate", 
    [
      {
        name: "Cocoa",
        isVerified: manufacturer2RawProductsMap["Milk"]
      },
      {
        name: "Sugar",
        isVerified: manufacturer2RawProductsMap["Sugar"]
      },
      {
        name: "Wheat",
        isVerified: manufacturer2RawProductsMap["Wheat"]
      }
    ],
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/dstmsi8qv/image/upload/v1652423805/Supply%20Chain/Product%20images/munch_nestle_lrjcal.jpg",
    {from: manufacturer2}
  );
  await manufacturerContract.launchProduct(22091, {from: manufacturer2});

  await productContract.add(
    22092, 
    "Tomato Sauce", 
    [
      {
        name: "Tomato",
        isVerified: manufacturer2RawProductsMap["Tomato"]
      },
      {
        name: "Sugar",
        isVerified: manufacturer2RawProductsMap["Sugar"]
      },
    ],
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/dstmsi8qv/image/upload/v1652423805/Supply%20Chain/Product%20images/tomato_sauce_nestle_w1vsqg.jpg",
    {from: manufacturer2}
  );
  await manufacturerContract.launchProduct(22092, {from: manufacturer2});

  await productContract.transfer(distributer, 12091, {from: manufacturer1});
  await productContract.addReview(12091, 70, "Good product", {from: distributer});
  await productContract.transfer(retailer1, 12091, {from: distributer});
  await productContract.addReview(12091, 90, "Value for money", {from: retailer1});
  await productContract.transfer(consumer1, 12091, {from: retailer1});
  await productContract.addReview(12091, 60, "Useful", {from: consumer1});
  console.log(await productContract.get(12091, {from: consumer1}));

  await productContract.transfer(distributer, 12092, {from: manufacturer1});
  await productContract.addReview(12092, 80, "Good product", {from: distributer});
  await productContract.transfer(retailer1, 12092, {from: distributer});
  await productContract.addReview(12092, 90, "Value for money", {from: retailer1});
  await productContract.transfer(consumer2, 12092, {from: retailer1});
  await productContract.addReview(12092, 100, "Good taste", {from: consumer2});
  console.log(await productContract.get(12092, {from: consumer2}));

  await productContract.transfer(distributer, 12093, {from: manufacturer1});
  await productContract.addReview(12093, 70, "Good product", {from: distributer});
  console.log(await productContract.get(12093, {from: consumer1}));

  await productContract.transfer(distributer, 22091, {from: manufacturer2});
  await productContract.addReview(22091, 70, "Good product", {from: distributer});
  await productContract.transfer(retailer2, 22091, {from: distributer});
  await productContract.addReview(22091, 90, "Value for money", {from: retailer2});
  await productContract.transfer(consumer2, 22091, {from: retailer2});
  await productContract.addReview(22091, 60, "Useful", {from: consumer2});
  console.log(await productContract.get(22091, {from: consumer2}));

  await productContract.transfer(distributer, 22092, {from: manufacturer2});
  await productContract.addReview(22092, 40, "Too Expensive", {from: distributer});
  await productContract.transfer(retailer2, 22092, {from: distributer});
  await productContract.addReview(22092, 90, "Tasty", {from: retailer2});
  await productContract.transfer(consumer1, 22092, {from: retailer2});
  await productContract.addReview(22092, 60, "Useful", {from: consumer1});
  console.log(await productContract.get(22092, {from: consumer1}));

  console.log("Stats: ")
  var count = await productContract.getProductsCount({from: consumer1});
  console.log("Products: " + count.words[0]);
  count = await productContract.getTransactionsCount({from: consumer2});
  console.log("Transactions: " + count.words[0]);
  count = await productContract.getReviewsCount({from: consumer2});
  console.log("Reviews: " + count.words[0]);

  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(admin));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(farmer1));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(farmer2));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(manufacturer1));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(manufacturer2));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(distributer));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(retailer1));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(retailer2));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(consumer1));
  console.log(await mainContract.getRole(consumer2));

}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Please i need help with it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `const Stakeholder = await ethers.getContract("Stakeholder");` try this:

```js
const Stakeholder = await ethers.getContractFactory("Stakeholder");
```